# Pandas reduce bar width and move label

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I use the following to reduce width of bars in Panda:

```
for container in ax.containers:
    plt.setp(container, width=.25)
```

However, on doing this, the labels on the x-axis remain at original position, as seen below. How can I move them to correspond to new bar width. In other words, is there a function to get the x coordinate of the center of each bar?

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot set the bar width at point of plot?

Comment: I am using the pandas plot command: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html It does not allow to set bar width when it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to set the width during `plot()`, something like this:

`df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=0.25, align='center')`

In the document it doesn't show you can set the **width**, but in fact it will take it as **kwds 
It will plot with the desired width with aligned x-axis labels.